# How to get the correct cell and show event information?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to show the event name and time for the user in the following format:

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qq8cD.jpg)

Left column containing the days in the month

The header contains the room names

If there is an event on that specific day, show the event title

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-efxdcw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Your stackblitz contains errors.

Comment: the error is _very_ explicit. On line 15 of the app.component.html you attempt to use a variable named `day` that is not defined on the module. Your intent is clear, that is to use it (`day`) from the previous definition (that resides in a closed loop and no longer exists).

Answer (score 0):

Working demo:
https://angular-ivy-wb8wbx.stackblitz.io

Code:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wb8wbx?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Explanation:

1. Group events by date and room id as follow

```js
     this.groups = this.events.reduce((result, event) => {
      const key = this.groupKeyGenerator(event.date, event.roomId)
      if (result.has(key)) {
        result.get(event.date).push(event);
      } else {
        result.set(key, [event]);
      }
      return result;
    }, new Map<string, Events>());
```

2. Loop through the date and room id then grab events for the date and room id as follow

```html
        <tr *ngFor="let day of days">
            <td>{{formatDate(day)}}</td>
            <td *ngFor="let room of rooms">
                <div *ngFor="let event of getEvents(day, room.id)">
                    <div>{{event.name}}</div>
                    <div>{{event.startTime}} - {{event.endTime}}</div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

Comment: using function in html is one of the worst way

Comment: this is just a sample... as the data is not "massaged" for the html... there are a lot of improvements if you want to talk best practices, eg. trackBy, changeDetectionStrategy, etc